# Yii2 count results related table

Tags: php, json, yii2

**This is in Nodes.php**

```
 public function getVoteLike()
{
    return  $this->hasMany(Votes::className(),['nid'=>'nid'])->where(['vote_type'=>"like"]);
}
```

**this is my query**

```
$model = new Nodes();
    $nodes  = $model->find()->select('nid,title,body,created,type_id')->with(['types',
        'voteLike'
        ,'voteDislike','categories'=>function($q){
        return $q->with('category');
    },
    'files'=>function($q){
        return $q->with('file');
    },
    ])->where(['type_id'=>2])->asArray()->limit(20)->all();
    echo json_encode($nodes);
```

**This result:**

```
[{"nid":"14","title":"- Eshitishimcha, qo'shnilaring juda ahil, huddi qo'sh kabuta","body":"<p>- Eshitishimcha, qo'shnilaring juda ahil, huddi qo'sh kabutarlarday yashasharmish.<br \/>\n- To'ppa-to'g'ri! Goh hotini oynadan otilib chiqadi, gohida eri.<\/p>\n","created":"1394091687","type_id":"2","types":{"tid":"2","type":"latifa","name":"Latifa","title_label":"Title","has_title":"1"},"voteLike":[{"vid":"335","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1395957819","vote_source":"173.245.54.226"},{"vid":"597","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1396071562","vote_source":"173.245.56.216"},{"vid":"1110","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1396258449","vote_source":"173.245.54.89"},{"vid":"1244","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1396327488","vote_source":"173.245.56.202"},{"vid":"1853","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1396541214","vote_source":"173.245.56.114"},{"vid":"2747","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1396777872","vote_source":"108.162.222.98"},{"vid":"6337","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1397262505","vote_source":"144.76.137.226"},{"vid":"26196","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1398990600","vote_source":"66.249.75.10"},{"vid":"79310","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1403034083","vote_source":"66.249.69.23"},{"vid":"134199","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1407961914","vote_source":"66.249.67.136"},{"vid":"187250","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1413374240","vote_source":"66.249.67.78"},{"vid":"224357","nid":"14","uid":"0","value":"1","vote_type":"like","timestamp":"1436920726","vote_source":"127.0.0.1"}],
```

**How can I get this result like that:**

```
[{"nid":"14","title":"- Eshitishimcha, qo'shnilaring juda ahil, huddi qo'sh kabuta","body":"<p>- Eshitishimcha, qo'shnilaring juda ahil, huddi qo'sh kabutarlarday yashasharmish.<br \/>\n- To'ppa-to'g'ri! Goh hotini oynadan otilib chiqadi, gohida eri.<\/p>\n","created":"1394091687","type_id":"2","types":{"tid":"2","type":"latifa","name":"Latifa","title_label":"Title","has_title":"1"},"voteLike":12,]
```